# Gradle - publish all project's dependencies to another artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory

As a software house, we are being asked, to deliver the software with all of its dependencies. The dependencies should be published to another artifactory. In another words - we would like to take all of the project's dependencies from our artifactory and publish them into another artifactory in a way that would enable the client to build the software.

Is there a way to do that in Gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bmuschko/e4e04abca105c397145e)

```
public class MavenArtifactCopyTask extends DefaultTask {
    @Input
    List<Configuration> configurations;

    @OutputDirectory
    File repoDir

    @TaskAction
    void build() {
        for (Configuration configuration : configurations) {
            copyJars(configuration)
            copyPoms(configuration)
        }
    }

    private void copyJars(Configuration configuration) {
        configuration.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { artifact ->
            def moduleVersionId = artifact.moduleVersion.id
            File moduleDir = new File(repoDir, "${moduleVersionId.group.replace('.','/')}/${moduleVersionId.name}/${moduleVersionId.version}")
            GFileUtils.mkdirs(moduleDir)
            GFileUtils.copyFile(artifact.file, new File(moduleDir, artifact.file.name))
        }
    }

    private void copyPoms(Configuration configuration) {
        def componentIds = configuration.incoming.resolutionResult.allDependencies.collect { it.selected.id }

        def result = project.dependencies.createArtifactResolutionQuery()
            .forComponents(componentIds)
            .withArtifacts(MavenModule, MavenPomArtifact)
            .execute()

        for(component in result.resolvedComponents) {
            def componentId = component.id

            if(componentId instanceof ModuleComponentIdentifier) {
                File moduleDir = new File(repoDir, "${componentId.group.replace('.','/')}/${componentId.module}/${componentId.version}")
                GFileUtils.mkdirs(moduleDir)                
                File pomFile = component.getArtifacts(MavenPomArtifact)[0].file
                GFileUtils.copyFile(pomFile, new File(moduleDir, pomFile.name))
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
task copyMavenArtifacts(type: MavenArtifactCopyTask) {
    configurations = [project.configurations.all, project.buildScript.configurations.classpath]
    repoDir = file("$buildDir/mavenArtifacts")
}
```

Once all the jars & poms are in a local folder in a maven directory structure you can

1. Upload them all to another repository
2. Use the folder as a maven repository

Comment: I have almost got where I wanted, using your suggestions. Thanks!
The problem, however, is that I don't know how to get the POM's parent POMs. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm... prehaps get the id's from `configuration.incoming.resolutionResult.allComponents` instead of `configuration.incoming.resolutionResult.allDependencies` (see [getAllComponents()](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/result/ResolutionResult.html#getAllComponents%28%29))

Comment: Let me know if it works. I might publish a plugin for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use repository replication https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication

Comment: The problem is that I cannot replicate all libraries but only the ones the project depends on.